# Use of Media Queries in CSS for iPad

Tags: ipad, css, mobile-safari, media-queries

Say I have an existing CSS for desktop (desktop.css). I want to include iPad Safari css.

In desktop.css, can we just do a condtional import at the end..

```
@media only screen and (device-width : 768px) 
{  
@import "ipad.css"
}
```

In ipad.css, we will have only iPad relevant styles..
/* iPad Styles */

i.e. if it is an iPad user, the ipad.css would get imported, else it would be ignored.

What is the best approach?

Comment: If you say "768px wide screen media" then design for "768px wide screen media" not "iPad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In desktop.css, can we just do a condtional import at the end..

Actually, no, `@import`s have to come before any other style declarations.

But in your case, if you import your iPad styles at the beginning they'll probably all get overridden by your desktop styles. So you're better off using another `<link>` element with that media query and pointing to your `ipad.css` instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (device-width: 768px)" href="ipad.css">
```

Comment: @BoltClock - Why are you using a fixed width check? The iPad dimensions are subject to change. Additionally, older desktop machines may actually have a width of 768px.

Comment: @Moshe: I really didn't think I'd need to concoct a holy-grail media query for my example when my point was to use a `<link>` instead of a conditional import because the latter wouldn't work - I just threw in what the OP already had for illustration. You can edit it to add a better media query if you wish.

Comment: What if I do the conditional @import at the end of desktop.css ? Is that possible?

Comment: @hmthur: It doesn't matter whether it's conditional or not. `@import` lines just have to be at the beginning of a stylesheet.

Comment: @BoltClock - No worries. `:-)` I was just pointing out that the said query is not something I'd want to copy and paste into my HTML file, for the aforementioned reasons.

Comment: So can we just use @import "ipad.css" at the beginning of desktop.css. Then in ipad.css, do the conditional check using @media only screen and (device-width : 768px)  ...and include the ipad styles there...Is that possible?

Comment: My main purpose is not to touch the actual page (which the <link media.. appraoch would) as well as including the iPad styles in a seperate CSS file...Thus I am wanting to use the @media approach..