# CSS Conditional @Import Question

Tags: html, css, ipad, media-queries

I have a HTML file which has the following code;

```
<html>
 <head>
  <LINK media="all" href="css/desktop.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <body>
  <span class="ipad_text">DESKTOP RED;  iPad GREEN</span>
<br />
  <span class="ipad_text2">DESKTOP BLACK;  iPad BLUE</span>
<br />
  <span class="ipad_only">iPad ONLY SHOW</span>
<br />
    <span class="ipad_only2">iPad ONLY 2</span>

 </body>
</html>
```

Also there are 2 CSS files under css folder (desktop.css and ipad.css);
In desktop.css, I have

```
@import "ipad.css";

.ipad_text{
    font:42px arial bold;
    color: red;
}


.ipad_text2{
    font:22px verdana bold;
    color: black;
}

.ipad_only{
    display:none;
}
```

And in ipad.css, I have

```
@media only screen and (device-width:768px)
{
.ipad_text{
    font:32px arial bold;
    color: green;
}

.ipad_text2{
    font:22px verdana bold;
    color: blue;
}

.ipad_only{
    display:block;
}

.ipad_only2{
    color: red;
    font:52px arial bold;
}

}
```

Now for some reasons, this is not working..If I cut/paste the code from ipad.css under the desktop.css file as follows, the page displays correctly in both desktop and iPad...What I am doing wrong? I want the 2 CSS to reside in separate files...Please help me.

Following works perfectly

```
@import "ipad.css";

.ipad_text{
    font:42px arial bold;
    color: red;
}


.ipad_text2{
    font:22px verdana bold;
    color: black;
}

.ipad_only{
    display:none;
}


@media only screen and (device-width:768px)
{
.ipad_text{
    font:32px arial bold;
    color: green;
}

.ipad_text2{
    font:22px verdana bold;
    color: blue;
}

.ipad_only{
    display:block;
}

.ipad_only2{
    color: red;
    font:52px arial bold;
}

}
```

Comment: When you import a stylesheet, it's `@import url("ipad.css");`.

Comment: Please suggest alternate ways by which I can have 1) Diff styles applied for desktop/ipad and 2) Have them in 2 separate CSS files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744223/use-of-media-queries-in-css-for-ipad/5744255#5744255)...

> `@import`s have to come before any other style declarations.
>
> But in your case, if you import your iPad styles at the beginning they'll probably all get overridden by your desktop styles.

... because your non-iPad styles apply to all media, *including* Mobile Safari on iPad. Since your non-iPad styles come after your conditional `@import`, they'll override your styles whether they get imported or not. This is normal [cascading](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cascade) behavior.

Comment: Hmmm...So is there any other way by which I could have diff styles applied for desktop/ipad as well as have them physically in 2 separate files?

Comment: When we say "@media not screen and (device-width: 768px) ", I think it would even exclude the desktop..bcoz of "not screen"..Right?

Comment: @hmthr: No, it means `not (screen and (device-width: 768px))`, read here http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Actually I did try that and for some reason styles under @media not screen and (device-width: 768px) do not get applied for the desktop.

Comment: @BoltClock: The media thing suggested by you is not working and now I see that you have removed it..

Comment: The answer provided to me earlier was incorrect and did not work. Could someone please help me. Thank you.

Comment: I rolled it back when you commented that it didn't work. I don't see any remaining part of my answer that's still worth a downvote.

Comment: So if you down vote the question, that is fine..But I  cannot do that !!