# `@media query` throw error, on import of different screen sizes

Tags: css

In my style folder I have 2 sub folder as `mobile` and `desktop` both of them imported in the main `style/app.css` file like:

`@import 'mobile/mobile';
@import 'desktop/desktop';`

It works fine. But I case, this import need to split in to 2 different screen sizes, so I do like :

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
 @import 'mobile/mobile';
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 769px) {
  @import 'desktop/desktop';
}
```

But not works. getting error as :

```
Error: You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
From "@extend .text-uppercase" on line 237 of tmp/sass_compiler-input_base_path-7VVKdugf.tmp/bootstrap/_type.scss
```

how can i fix this? any one please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports needs to be done before any style declaration.
But regarding to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744223/use-of-media-queries-in-css-for-ipad/5744255#5744255) answer, you can do the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 768px)" href="mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px)" href="desktop.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
@import url("desktop/desktop") only screen and (min-device-width: 769px);
```

or you can do this in SASS:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 769px) {
    @import "desktop/desktop";
}
```

and will generate into:

```
@import url("desktop/desktop") only screen and (min-device-width: 769px);
```